# How to build a proper DB schema to have "periodic snapshots" of a table for a selected day?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

**Problem to be solved:**
Im new to DataBases and Im trying to find out the best way to store changes in a table, that is a daily snapshot of some statuses: eg. "hotel_room_rentals" table (with 20 columns - every can change).
Id like to be able to generate that table for a selected day (e.g. data inside changes on production, so I have to store it somewhere else), or do some other transformations on it (e.g. average number of days rented in a period)

**My theoretical example - detailed:**
Let's say that Im creating a DB for a hotel.
In the production system I have a table that shows info for all 10 000 rooms in the hotel.
This is a daily snapshot - let's assume that the table is updated once per day.

Some attributes of a room change often: e.g. is_rented; customer_number, rate_usd.
Some attributes dont change too often: e.g. disabled_room, room_color, type_of_furniture.
Room_number obviously does not change (primary key)

Now I want to find the best way to track changes in this table; the best way to create statistics on base of this table (e.g. average number of days rented in a period) and to be able to generate the table for selected date (e.g. 2013-01-01)

**MY IDEA:**
Since I have no clue about databases, my idea is to copy the whole table every day, with 1 more column, called "DB_dump_date" (with a date). This is a pretty straightforward approach, which will probably require a lot of space; since my 10k rooms table, will have to be copied 365 times in a year.

**OTHER SOLUTIONS:**
On some other website, I was recommended to create two tables:
"Reservation" table with these columns: Startdate Enddate Room Rate Occupant_name
Then to transform this table into a FactReservations table: Date Room Is_occupied Rate Occupant_name
I do not understand how does this help me... in fact I assume I would have to make 20 intermediary tables and then 20 Fact tables (since I have 20 columns in my database).

**QUESTIONS:**
What are the recommended ways to deal with such problems?
Is there any DB schema that is prepared to deal with it, without the user making magic ETLs? (e.g. a DB that can optimize the problem by itself)
What are the alternatives?
How would you, smart people, do this? (preferably in MS Access... or some freeware technology)

**edit:**
one more thing - everything can change in the table, not only room reservetions, everything; and I want to be able to track the changes

Comment: @fledgeling . . . It is great that you want to learn about databases.  However, if this is a real business problem, you should find someone who has experience with databases and data modeling to help with this problem.  You do not know how to judge whether a particular solution is good or not, and a poorly designed database can endanger the application.

Comment: Sounds like you want to read http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#section_3

Answer (score 2):

stop - slow down - and take a breath.

do not - repeat do not make copies of tables each day. this approach is way off base.

your problem is a normalization problem.  as you indicate - you have other suggestions on how to normalize - this is the direction you want to go.

Your goal will be to find a structure that accommodates the SQL statements that can answer your questions (and hopefully many more that you haven't thought up yet)  This will be one static model where the tables do not change or get copied, but are instead static - and the only thing that changes is the data inside the tables. (ideally - to me there will also be few to no updates, only inserts)

You will certainly need a ROOM table, and a CUSTOMER table, and then a relation between them possibly RESERVATION.

these can then fill up - and you can get all the answers to the questions you posed without any copying or materialization or anything.. just SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but Im not sure if it helps; I know that there are other solutions, but I dont know them and I dont see any beneift in some weird logic, that will mean 20 additional other tables, 20 ETLs and then 20 FactTables (as I wrote, every column can change). I know that I can connect customer_number with customer information, but this is irrelevant

Comment: the problem is in your design of a 20 column table.  This needs to be NORMALIZED - a rule of thumb is a table should have 5-7 columns max.. see if you can get to 3rd normal form

Comment: Im trying to learn what is the best practice for such cases. Dividing the table sounds like an interesting idea; but I still dont really see the benefit, because when I divide something into 20 reservation tables + 20 fact tables the information still needs to be copied, so it sits somewhere (but I guess the operations on it are easier to be run). Is there in fact any other benefit, of copying something in 20 parts, instead of making 1 big copy? If you are really interested, I have a similar problem, created by the "consultants" and have to solve it as an end user - want to learn best practice

Comment: If by normalization you mean that each column is unique, than all 20 columns are unique; in fact in real life example, 200 columns are unique. The only cause of copied data would be a "data_base_dump_date" column (that would be a copy of all rows for selected day); but I wonder if there are better ways of solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to focus on the requirements and start there. So far for requirements I see are:

-Generate that table for a selected day

-average number of days rented in a period

If we consider two extremes of design, at the more complex end would be a datamart with SCD tables, tracking changes to rooms, and at the simple end would be some kind of log table, along the lines of what you have already mentioned.

Reading between the lines, I don't really see any requirement for knowing the attributes of a room on a given day, but I do see a requirement for analysis of historical transactions.

So my suggestion is have a good hard think about your requirements before you start designing the database.

There is no magic design to cover this automatically. Dimensional design is a standard way of modelling business data to allow for easy analysis, but it might be over the top for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of databases! With that in mind – take almost everything that you know about Excel and throw it out the window. Whereas it’s much more difficult in Excel to define relationships between two sheets of a workbook and report off of those two different sheets, so the majority of the time it’s easier to simply copy the same data down a single sheet, it’s trivially easy to do using Access or any other relational database.

Typically what you’d want to do is create several normalized tables and define a relationship between them. Then, when querying the view, you can easily join between the tables to get the data that you need.

So, working off of the assumption that you’re building this for simple reporting and not to create a property management system (if you are looking at that – I’d recommend that you look at some of the players in the industry, like Micros or Agilysys), based on my experience working in the industry, I’d recommend the following table layout:

- Reservations – this holds the reservation information (guest name,
  arrival date, departure date, check-in date, check-out date, rate if
  you use a blended rate, etc.)
- Rooms – this holds information on your rack (number, wing code, max
  guests, # beds, smoking/non, view, type, etc.)
- Room Status – Only if you need to track if a room is on
  reserve/hold/OOO/OTM (Status type, date start, date end)
- Room Status Types – Types of room status holds and how it affects
  inventory (type, out of inventory flag)
- Rates (if you don’t use a blended rate) – one entry per reservation
  per night (guest, rate)

Personally, I’m a huge fan of using [surrogate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) for the unique identifiers, because all too often I've been burned where something changes in the business process and a natural key that was previously unique all of a sudden can be duplicated.  In that vein, each table would have a surrogate key and the joins would be  as follows:

- Reservations – Rooms (many  to one)
- Rooms – Room Status (one to many)
- Room Status – Room Status Types (many to one)
- Reservations – Rates (one to many)

If you define the relationships properly in Access (i.e. foreign key relationships in other DBMS), it should automatically use them to build your joins when creating your queries (called Views in just about every other DBMS) or reports.

For learning about databases I’d recommend that you review:

- [Wikipedia on Join types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)
- [Wikipedia on Slowly Changing Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) (you could use some of
  these techniques to record changes in room information over time)
- [Wikipedia on Relational Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)
- [Office documentation on Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-database-tasks-HA101829991.aspx)
- [Kimball Group Design Tips](http://www.kimballgroup.com/category/design-tips/) (great for data warehouse/datamart
  design)

Comment: The IT head (does not work here any more), hired consultants (dont work here any more + they actually got sued for this) created a flat table with 200 columns and around 30 000 rows (increase of 50 rows per month) that stores some information. There is an unique key for each row. When I write that it is unique, then it means that it is unique, so please do not come back with some smart ass reply.

Creating such a monster - sounds pretty retarded - and that's what it is, but as I wrote the retards who made it, dont work here any more.

Comment: Anyway in this table there are around 20-30 (who knows) columns there change quickly (every day - few days). Rest change slowly, dont ask me how often is slowly - the table does not have a dictionary and I dont know the stuff in some columns. Anyway, I inherited that crap table from those idiots and have to work on it - sort of. Basically I need to make some statistics on around 5-10 (who knows?) columns -> some usually "average status" during month (the hotel ANALOGY is useful here - something like "average days rented"); I also need to be able to generate this table for a selected day.

Comment: Working with Access (2gb max size per database) - this would be similar to taking a daily snapshot of a hotel and working out the dimensions (i.e. Rooms, Reservations, etc.) and your facts (i.e. Rates), you would work out the items that don't change/slowly change and put them into dimensions (regular dimensions if they don't change, type 1 or 2 if you don't or do want to maintain dimension history, respectively) and then build the measure/fact tables joining to the dimensions. Any DB should be able to handle inner joins on millions of rows with ease. The Kimball Group has some great pointers.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use your existing table then the following is not applicable. If the data can be migrated to a new schema then this will readily address the challenge. TRE is an approach which uses the current view paradigm for development but fully supports the time dimensions of data (which are system time=when the data goes into the db and valid time=the business time which applies to the data). By working in the current view approach of TRE this sort of problem is straightforward. Take a look at:- http://youtu.be/V1EcsuJxUno